# How to prevent add_editor_style from running?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, plugins, hook

I was wondering how I could prevent `add_editor_style( $protocol.$universal_css_url );` from running by using my own functions.php (so I mean via a hook or something like that)?

Is there a way to disable or remove this? Like: `remove_editor_style( $protocol.$universal_css_url );` That would be great! Unfortunately this code is not working..

Thank you!

Comment: add_editor_style adds stylesheets to the global $editor_styles array variable. You can try to clear that array!?

Comment: By clear i mean to remove the unwanted styleheet from the array.

Comment: Ah Great! How do I remove something from the $editor_styles array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code example, this should get you started!?

```
function theme_remove_editor_styles() {
    // Get the global var
    global $editor_styles;
    // Get the item you want to move
    $entry_to_move = $editor_styles[4];
    // Remove a specific entry
    unset($editor_styles[4]);
    // Add the entry back to the beginning of the array
    array_unshift($editor_styles, $entry_to_move);
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'theme_remove_editor_styles', 100);
```

Comment: Thank you! I see in the printed array, that the last element is the one I want to get rid of. Is there a way to send this last element to the beginning of the array? That would be even better!

Comment: I have edited my answer above. This should move the item to the beginning. You wil have to change the index though.